# Issue with Bundle in android

Tags: android, database, listview, if-statement

I had put a String value (Edittext input from user in my Search-Activity) in Bundle. Then I had got the Bundle (Result-Activity) to check if the user left the Edittext with no value. But It's not working. If statement have something wrong. It seems like nothing was checked. I debugged and saw first "If" being executed and then "Else". Can someone help me?

Search-Activity:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDbHelper = new SBooksDbAdapter(this);
        mDbHelper.open();
        setContentView(R.layout.sbooks_search); 

        mTextSearch = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.text_search);     
        searchButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_search);

        mTextSearch.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mTextSearch.setHint(R.string.button_hint);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){        
                    startSearch();                                  
            }
        });
    }
    // Start Activity Search Result
    public void startSearch(){                  
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();       
        bundle.putString(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW, mTextSearch.getText().toString());

        Intent intentSearch = new Intent(this, SBooksSearchResult.class);
        intentSearch.putExtras(bundle);     
        this.startActivity(intentSearch);           
    }
```

Result-Acitity:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();        
    String searchText = bundle.getString(SBooksDbAdapter.KEY_TITLE_RAW);        

    if(searchText != "")
    {
        // Do nothing           
    }
    else {  
        searchText = "Hello" ;
    }
```

Comment: 1. You can call getStringExtra() on the Intent -- you do not need to call getExtras() and then make later calls to getString().

2. A missing Bundle value returns null from getString(), not "".

3. You may wish to post the code where you are calling putExtra() to store the value in the Intent. Without that, and perhaps other code, it will be difficult to assist you.

Comment: Hi, I post the code as you comment. And one thing, I debug (too many times) and found that searchText value is "", not null. Hope you could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
if (searchText != "")
```

try:

```
if (!searchText.equals(""))
```